# How to create integration tests in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, testing, devops

I'm new to devops life, now I have a task to create integration tests for a project, but Selenium is not used in the project. Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need to create the "VS TEST" task. It is necessary to specify 2 parameters "Test file" and "Test filter" in it. Since there was an integration test in my task, I indicated in the field "Test file" **/mytestfile.csptoj[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAKzY.png) And in the field "Test filter" FullyQualifiedName ~ Integration